# Performance issue with traversing&&filtering datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Currently, I am doing a log analyzer for my personal project.
My issue here is that I am new to c# and I have an performance issue with my tool.

Everytime the device(iOS) is interacted, I get an output syslog from a library and it comes in to the output handler.

```
public void OutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine, iosSyslogger form, string uuid)
    {
        string currentPath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        bool exit = false;
        if (exit == true) return;

        try
        {
            form.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                form.insertLogText = outLine.Data;
            }));


           using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(currentPath + @"\syslog" + uuid + ".txt", true))
           {
             file.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
           }

        }
        catch 
        {
            return ;
        }
        //*Most of the logic for outputing the log should be dealt from this output Handler
    }
```

Then, I write the outline.Data to Data grid view. My concern is that I need to be able to search and filter through data gridview.

Curently I am using visibility = false for search filtering ( if the row does not match the given filter specification I set the row to visibility =false)

This requires the program to traverse the entire datagridview to check whether the condition is met.

Will there be any better way to filter and search within ? 
(When I have thousands of lines of row, it takes at least 20 seconds to process it)
Below is the code for filtering, and searching through the results function.

```
 private void searchResult(string term)
    {
        if (term != null)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3] == null)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible == false)
                {
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(term) || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Contains(term) || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString().Contains(term))
                {
                    string multirow = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(multirow);
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        int z = 0;
                        for (z = 0; z <= count; z++)
                        {

                            dataGridView1.Rows[i + z].Visible = true;
                        }
                        i = i + z;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

public filteringThelist(){

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
            int count1,count2,count3=0;
            count1 = 1;
            count2 = 1;
            count3 = 1;
            int z = 0;

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in totalSelected)
            {

                if (entry.Value == "devicename" && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(entry.Key.Trim()))
                    {
                        string multirow1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                        int counts = Convert.ToInt32(multirow1);
                        if (counts > 0)
                        {
                            for (z = 0; z < counts; z++)
                            {

                                dataGridView1.Rows[i + z].Visible = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (devicename.CheckedItems.Count > 1&&count1!= devicename.CheckedItems.Count)
                    {
                        count1++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (entry.Value == "process" && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim().Equals(entry.Key.Trim()))
                    {
                        string multirow1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                        int counts = Convert.ToInt32(multirow1);
                        if (counts > 0)
                        {
                            for (z = 0; z < counts; z++)
                            {

                                dataGridView1.Rows[i + z].Visible = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (processlistname.CheckedItems.Count > 1 && count2 != processlistname.CheckedItems.Count)
                    {
                        count2++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (entry.Value == "loglevel" && dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value != null)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim().Contains(entry.Key.Trim()))
                    {
                        string multirow1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                        int counts = Convert.ToInt32(multirow1);
                        if (counts > 0)
                        {
                            for (z = 0; z < counts; z++)
                            {

                                dataGridView1.Rows[i + z].Visible = true;
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (loglevelCheckBox.CheckedItems.Count > 1 && count3 != loglevelCheckBox.CheckedItems.Count)
                    {
                        count3++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
            }
            string multirow = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(multirow);
            if (count > 0&& dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible==false)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k <= count; k++)
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows[i + k].Visible = false;
                }

            }

            i = i + z;




        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance problem is because your DataGridView is redrawing at each modification.

Don't fill the DataGridView directly from your Data. Rather create a DataTable and bind it to DataGridView with a BindingSource.

Then use the "Filter" property of the binding source to view extracts of dataTable in the DataGridView. The "Filter" property is a string whose content is similar to that of a WHERE SQL clause.